# How to dynamically change sql query to add week numbers?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a sql query where I need to provide trailing six week numbers in my `IN` clause. I have removed other details as part of this query just to keep things simple. As you can see below everything is hardcoded as of now. And every week I change below query and add new week number and remove oldest one to keep trailing 6 weeks.

```
AND data.process_holder IN ('21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26')
```

How can I make this query dynamic in such a way so that it can automatically change week numbers for me by keeping trailing six weeks. For example: For current week it should take this whenever we run it. And similarly it should for every week.

```
AND data.process_holder IN ('22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27')
```

Is this possible to do? I am using AWS Redshift database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try comparing the week number from `process_holder` against the week number from the current date:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ... AND
    process_holder::integer BETWEEN DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE) - 5 AND
                                    DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE);
```

Comment: Aah we can write it like that? hmm thats interesting. I wasn't aware of that. Learned something new today. Is there any doc on how to use `::` in sql?

Comment: @AndyP You could have also just used `CAST(process_holder AS integer)`, but maybe you don't even need the cast if `process_holder` is actually already numeric.

Comment: Hi Tim, Do you think you can help with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449161/how-to-dynamically-change-sql-query-to-add-dates-of-the-week-and-all-week-number) as well. It's mostly same as this question.